# Linux User access control

Tags: linux, user-controls, access-control

How do I in a shell script assign users a label? I have the script to create a new user, but cannot figure out how to assign a new user being created a label, and then stores the label for the users in a file only accessible by root.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Enter username : " username
    read -s -p "Enter password : " password
    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username exists!"
        exit 1
    else
        pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
        useradd -m -p "$pass" "$username"
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
    fi
else
    echo "Only root may add a user to the system."
    exit 2
fi
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how and why you want to pick labels. Simplest thing is you write user name and label to a new file that only root can read. Have you tried that? What happened? What do you want to do with the user labels anyway? Have you looked into [SE Linux contexts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts-selinux_contexts_for_users)? Also, why do you write a wrapper around `useradd`? It checks for root and prompts on its own. Maye [ask] would help.

Comment: This was for an assignment. I believe it can be done in SE Linux but our professor was extremely vague and later explained to do it in a conceptual way rather than actual implementation. The labels are supposed to act as a way to determine what levels of access new users have as they are created based on their labels. As for the wrapper the code above is from the lab provided to us and is very old so that may have something to do with it.